# When using 'yum list available' why are some entries in blue?

Tags: centos, yum

Using iTerminal on Mac OS X 10.8 to connect via SSH to a CentOS 6.4 server, running `yum list available` will show a list of packages available from the various repositories on that machine. Some of the entries' names are shown in blue. I'm not sure what significance that formatting has. Why are some installed packages shown in blue?

[image: ss of terminal w/ colored rpms]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [man page for yum](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) explains it as follows:

> ```
>    --color=[always|auto|never]
>           Display colorized output automatically, depending on the output 
>           terminal, always (using ANSI codes) or never. Note that  some
>           commands (Eg. list and info) will do a little extra work when 
>           color is enabled.  Configuration Option:
>           color
> ```

Further if you read the [yum.conf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf):

1. Red: ‘bold,red’:

   - packages in list/info installed which has no available package with the same name and arch.
2. Yellow: ‘bold,yellow’:

   - packages in list/info installed which are newer than the latest available package with the same name and arch.
3. Blue: ‘bold,blue’:

   - packages in list/info available which is an upgrade for the latest installed package with the same name and arch.
4. Cyan: ‘dim,cyan’:

   - packages in list/info available which is a downgrade for the latest installed package with the same name and arch.
5. White: ‘bold’:

   - packages in list/info installed which are older than the latest available package with the same name and arch.
6. White and underlined: ‘bold,underline’:

   - kernel packages in list/info installed which is the same version as the running kernel.